# What's the meaning of "くべて" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, words, song-lyrics

"花をくべて　歌をくべて"
I tried to search for the meaning and the only thing I got was something like "throw fire in something" that for me at least doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3):

You've got it backwards. 焼べる means to add something to a fire to make it burn. Used metaphorically I suppose it could represent adding elements (such as flowers and song) to an occasion to make it more 'burn brighter'. It would help if you had mentioned the name of the song (月と花束）in your post.

Below is from a [Spanish translation](http://mahou-kashi.blogspot.com/2018/02/sayuri-tsuki-to-hanataba.html) of this part of the song:

```
Arrojo flores al fuego

Arrojo canciones al fuego
```

> 花をくべて　歌をくべて
>
> 誰より険しく　美しく
>
> あの日の傷も　貰った愛も
>
> すべてくべて光の方へ

As it is a song, it is hard to translate it literally. Here is the gist:

> Throw flowers into the fire
>
> Throw songs into the fire
>
> More harsh and beautiful than anyone
>
> The pain of that day and the love that was received
>
> Throw it all into the the light

Comment: 「光の方へ」 って、the brightness ensues になるんでしょうか・・? 普通は toward the light とか in the direction of the light とか closer to the place where it's bright (明るい場所の近くへ) みたいな意味ですよね・・・　「花をくべて　歌をくべて　... すべてくべて」って、「花も歌も傷も愛も全て、光のほうへくべてください」って言ってるんじゃないんですかね・・

Comment: You're right, I just thought I would take some artistic license on that part. Shall modify.

Comment: あ、いやでも確信ないですよ？　PV見たけどいまいち不明です。「（私が？あなたが？私たちが？）花も歌も傷も全部くべて、光の方に行くor行こう・・」かもしれないし、「全部、光にくべてください。」って頼んでいるのかもしれないし・・

Comment: 正直言いますが、歌を聞かなかったです。最後の方について迷って、「光の方へ」くべるか行くか、意味がちょっと微妙だったので適当にやりました。'I'も入れたことは個人的に選択しました。とりあえず、人称代名詞をなくしました。